# phpmyadmin is hung

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin running on a remote VPS. It has been working fine for months. Today I tried to import a new table but it hung up with a message saying the file is being processed - please be patient. After an hour of being patient I closed phpmyadmin. Now when I try to access it the browser just hangs their trying to connect. The table that I was importing was just an empty structure with no data, i.e. small file. I have done this many times in the past with no issues.

The website is still working fine and is able to access the mysql database. I can log on to mysql remotely through SSH and it appears to be working OK. I am sorry if this is the wrong place to ask but can anyone suggest the best way to diagnose this and connect to phpmyadmin again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried restarting Apache, MySQL, or the entire server?

`service ___ restart`

or

`/etc/init.d/___ restart`

Where *_*: apache2, httpd, and/or mysqld, depending on your setup.

Comment: Thanks djdy. I must admit I was nervous about doing this in case I broke something but I have done it now. Re-starting mysql did not fix it but restarting apache was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all cookies which were set by that phpmyadmin.

If it doesn't work, I think your only solution is to contact the company which provides the VPS and ask them for help.

PS: Have you tried connecting to the phpmyadmin from a different PC ?